# How to get the right "version" of a database entry?

Tags: mysql

**Update: Question refined, I still need help!**

**I have the following table structure:**

table `reports`:

```
ID |       time | title | (extra columns)
 1 | 1364762762 |   xxx | ...
```

Multiple `object` tables that have the following structure

```
ID | objectID |       time | title | (extra columns)
 1 |        1 | 1222222222 | ...   | ...
 2 |        2 | 1333333333 | ...   | ...
 3 |        3 | 1444444444 | ...   | ...
 4 |        1 | 1555555555 | ...   | ...
```

In the object tables, on an object update a new version with the same objectID is inserted, so that the old versions are still available. For example see the entries with `objectID = 1`

In the reports table, a `report` is inserted but never updated/edited.

**What I want to be able to do is the following:**

For each entry in my `reports` table, I want to be able to query the state of *all* objects, like they were, when the `report` was created.

For example lets look at the sample report above with ID 1. At the time it was created (see the `time` column), the current version of objectID 1 was the entry with ID 1 (entry ID 4 did not exist at that point).
ObjectID 2 also existed with it's current version with entry ID 2.

**I am not sure how to achieve this.**

I could use a query that selects the object versions by the time column:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM   objects
    WHERE  time < [reportTime]
    ORDER BY time DESC
)
GROUP BY objectID
```

Lets not talk about the performance of this query, it is just to make clear what I want to do. My problem is the comparison of the time columns. I think this is no good way to make sure that I got the right object versions, because the system time may change *"for any reason"* and the time column would then have wrong data in it, which would lead to wrong results.

What would be another way to do so?
I thought about not using a time column for this, but instead a **GLOBAL** incremental value that I know the insertion order across the database tables.

Comment: There are a few ways to achieve this, can you edit your question with some schema information (including indexes) and maybe even a few rows of example data - this will help someone suggest the best way to do it

Comment: I am still building up the schema, the count of columns differs for each table. I also can create as much indexes as needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interting new versions of the object, and your problem is the `time` column(I assume you are using this column to sort which one is newer); I suggest you to use an `auto-incremental ID` column for the versions. Eventually, even if the `time` value is not reliable for you, the `ID` will be.Since it is always increasing. So higher ID, newer version.

Comment: I also have an auto-incremental ID for the tables